# Delete custom schema from directory yields error 400

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to delete a custom schema from my G-Suite directory.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/schemas?fields=schemas(schemaId%2CschemaName)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
{
 "schemaId": "wAq9Qg4MR3-2Y647IvNb6w==",
 "schemaName": "SSO",
 "fields": [
  {
   "fieldId": "ZHzd3CDzQYmnEkJH9VDwhg==",
   "fieldName": "awsRole",
   "multiValued": true
  }
 ]
}
```

When trying to use the `DELETE` method I get the following:

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/schemas/SSO?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Input: ZHzd3CDzQYmnEkJH9VDwhg=="
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Input: ZHzd3CDzQYmnEkJH9VDwhg=="
 }
}
```

I'm using https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/admin/directory_v1/directory.schemas.delete in cases that matters, but the same happens when trying via: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/schemas/delete.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Confusingly enough, the `Invalid input` indicated in the error corresponds to the `fieldId` in the custom schema.

How do I delete the custom schema from my G Suite directory?

Answer (score 3):

The schema can not be referenced in any SAML application attribute mapping. When you delete the mapping you can then delete the schema.

Comment: Could it be another reason? I do not have any SAML applications in my G Suite at all (not any more)

Comment: This worked for me. After dropping the mapping in the SAML application you can delete it.